why the pywin32 service work when running by administrator account but not work by local system account?
I wrote a python script running as windows service to reversely forward a port. The service works ok when it logged on by the administrator account. But when it logged on by local system account, the service still runs but not work. Why?
I have added the /python and /python/Scripts to the system path. The following is my code:
import time
import sys
import subprocess as sp

import win32serviceutil  # ServiceFramework and commandline helper
import win32service  # Events
import servicemanager  # Simple setup and logging

class MyService:
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        rport=55009
        cmd=f'ssh  -fNR {rport}:127.0.0.1:3389 username@remotehost -p 22'
        cmd1='ssh -tt  username@remotehost -p 22  \"netstat -tpa | grep \'**:{} **\'\"'.format(rport)
        while True:
            a=sp.run(cmd1,capture_output=True,shell=True).stdout.decode("utf-8") 
            # print('one turn')
            if f":{rport}" not in a:
                try:
                    p=sp.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
                    p.wait(2)
                except sp.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
                except:
                    print('execution failed')
            elif not "ESTABLISHED" in a:
                cmd2="\"ps aux | grep '**xiaoya**'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill\""
                cmd2="ssh -tt  username@remotehost -p 22 "+cmd2
                try: 
                    a=sp.run(cmd2,shell=True)
                    p=sp.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
                    p.wait(2)
                except sp.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
                except:
                    print('execution failed')
            time.sleep(5*1)
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Service running...")


class MyServiceFramework(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'autossh1'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'autossh1'

    def SvcStop(self):
    
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_impl.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        self.service_impl = MyService()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        # Run the service
        self.service_impl.run()


def init():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyServiceFramework)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceFramework)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()

Besides, I have also tested running other commands such as "date /t". Then the service works ok logged by local system account.

em, answer by myself. Reimplementing the function by C# and ssh.net can avoid the problem.

Please share your solution with the community. Other people might find it useful down the road.
